# Middle-click scrolling with ThinkPad/avoid pasting

Tags: x11, mouse, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad USB keyboard, and I want to be able to use the middle click both for pasting and scrolling.

This works on my ThinkPad laptop. On the laptop, if the middle click button is held for a short enough amount of time, then when it is released it is interpreted as "**paste**." When held for longer, it is interpreted as "**scroll**."

The problem is that, using the USB keyboard, the decision to paste occurs when the middle button is **pressed**, not when it is **released**, so if I try to scroll with middle click, it will paste first, then scroll when I keep holding it down (though interestingly, this paste does not occur if I am already moving the cursor, which is my current workaround).

Is there a way to tell X11 to paste on middle button release rather than press (with the decision to scroll rather than paste being made based on how long it was held for)?

Comment: It's surprising to hear that the behaviour of X11 would be different depending on which mouse is being used. I suggest using `xev` to watch for the `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease` events to see if your laptop's button is really sending the events you think it is at the time you think it is. It's possible that it's doing some of its own magic instead and "lying" to X11 about when the buttons are pressed and released. By the way, it appears to be normal that paste occurs immediately upon *press* of button 2, not *release*.

Comment: I would also love to know how to do this as I'm on a Lenovo Bluetooth Trackpoint Keyboard.

Comment: That USB keyboard, what exact model is that? Does it have a "real" touchpad or a so-called clickpad (with no physical buttons)? Also, what distro and desktop environment do you use? Is there any special xorg configuration in place ( /etc/X11/xorg.conf and in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ ) ?  


You may find some pointers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2557/thinkpad-middle-button-scrolling and for clickpad here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/380825/trackpoint-and-clickpad-enable-buttons-and-scroll-lenovo-t440s

Comment: Any updates on this? I am experiencing the same issue with an external Lenovo keyboard.

Comment: FWIW, I have two models of bluetooth trackpoint keyboard, and one has this problem. `xev` shows that the `ButtonPress` for button 2 as soon as I click, then `ButtonRelease` when I start to scroll. What should happen is that neither of these events are generated until the action is disambiguated by either moving the trackpoint (in which case neither press or relase are generated) or button 2 is released (in which case, both events are sent upon release).

Answer (score 3):

Try enabling scroll emulation with the following commands, which work well on several models of trackpoint keyboard:

```
dev="TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
xinput --set-int-prop "$dev" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 8 6 7 4 5
xinput --set-int-prop "$dev" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 8 2
xinput --set-int-prop "$dev" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 1
```

If you don't like that, you can undo it with

```
xinput --set-int-prop "$dev" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 0
```

You may need to adjust dev based on your model of keyboard.  Run

```
xinput --list | grep TrackPoint
```

to see what your pointing device is called.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I have the external Lenovo TrackPoint Keyboard II, and the device I had to use was "Lenovo TrackPoint Keyboard II Mouse"

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-thinkpad.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Trackpoint Wheel Emulation"
    MatchProduct    "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint|DualPoint Stick|Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint|ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint|USB Trackpoint pointing device|Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option      "EmulateWheel"      "true"
    Option      "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option      "Emulate3Buttons"   "false"
    Option      "XAxisMapping"      "6 7"
    Option      "YAxisMapping"      "4 5"
EndSection
```

The important section is the `MatchProduct` entry, which includes also the USB keyboard.  You can find the keyboard product string in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` by grepping for `(II) evdev:`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my new Lenovo ThinkPad Trackpoint Keyboard II.

What worked for me was to update to kernel 5.19 and load [the `hid-lenovo` kernel module](https://www.kernelconfig.io/config_hid_lenovo).
Support for Lenovo ThinkPad Trackpoint Keyboard II [only landed in kernel 5.19](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/547#note_1379498).

Now the unwanted pasting when clicking the middle button is gone and I can even scroll horizontally with the TrackPoint! \o/